# How can I validate a wordpress user using php externally

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm using GD php to inject an image into an  HTML tag and I want to make sure that the Wordpress user can access the image.

I have an img tag on my Wordpress page which generates an image from data extracted from the database.

```
<img src=\""+imagepath+"image.php?file="+fn+"&layout="+layout+"&w="+window.innerWidth+"&h="+window.innerHeight+"\" />
```

Contents of image.php:

```
<?php
  include_once('../../../wp-load.php');
  $current_user = wp_get_current_user();
  $userID=$current_user->ID;
  error_log("\n".$userID."-:-\n");
  $path=realpath('.').'/';
  $width=$_GET['w'];
  $height=$_GET['h'];
  $im = ImageCreate($width,$height); 
  $white = ImageColorAllocate($im,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF); 
  $black = ImageColorAllocate($im,0x00,0x00,0x00);
  ImageFilledRectangle($im,50,50,$width-100,$height-100,$black);
  imagefttext($im,12,0,60,60,$white,$path."ARIAL.TTF",$userID);
  imagefttext($im,12,0,60,160,$white,$path."ARIAL.TTF",$_GET['file']);
  header('Content-Type: image/png');
  ImagePNG($im);
?>
```

I'm guessing that 'wp-load.php' defines the header which will conflict with 'Content-Type: image/png'.

Is there a way that I can validate the user so that I can see whether he should have access to the image? I also need access to the database, but I'm pretty sure that I can include wp-config.php for DB_NAME, etc although I haven't tested that yet.

Comment: Are you just “guessing” or do you get an actual error / problem?

Comment: I am indeed, just guessing. There are no errors in /var/log/nginx/error.log. The image is just not displayed.

Comment: Go check in browser dev tools how the request gets answered, check headers & body content.

Comment: The browser dev tools give me the information for the main page, but not for the image. If I remove the include('wp-load.php') and associated calls, the image loads as expected.

Comment: The network panel should show the request for the image URL as well.

Comment: Thanks. It loads 200 OK and the type is given as 'text/html'

Comment: Embedding `wp-load.php` should not prevent the script from issuing its own Content-Type header. What does the response body look like? Any PHP error messages in there maybe?

Comment: The size is given as 2 numbers, 244B and 10B but I don't see anywhere (using Chrome) where I can see the content. The Firefox Dev tools console doesn't even show that much.

Comment: The network panel should have preview/response tabs (or similar) in the request details.

Comment: Under Request Headers I see this: Accept: image/webp,image/*,*/*;q=0.8.
Under Response it says "No Response Data available." Under Preview it says "No Preview Data available".

Comment: Sounds like the script simply dies due to an error. Do you have proper PHP error reporting enabled?

Comment: I've got error_reporting set to E_ALL and display_error set to "On" in /etc/php/7.2/cli/php.ini although phpinfo() says that the latter is set to "Off"

Comment: `cli` in that path likely means that is the php.ini to be used when you execute PHP via command line - so you are looking at the wrong one. phpinfo shows what configuration file was actually used in the top section.

Comment: Thanks very much for your help. I have managed to track the error down to a function in my plugin which I had inadvertently called from the root of a php file. Thank you for your patience. Much appreciated.